# Express JS route with POST request returns 404 Cannot GET error in Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am creating APIs in Nodejs using express and body-parser. I am able to successfully make the GET requests using postman but when using POST request it always throws error **404 not found Cannot GET /**

- Express Version :@4.17.1
- Body Parser Version: @1.19.0

Please check the code below

***server.js file***

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");

var addRequestId = require('express-request-id')();
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
const cron = require("node-cron");
const cluster = require('cluster');
const os = require('os');
const v1 = require('./routes/v1');
const jobs = require('./routes/jobs/sync_job');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Check if current process is master.
if (cluster.isMaster) {

  // Get total CPU cores.
  const cpuCount = os.cpus().length;

  // Spawn a worker for every core.
  for (let j = 0; j < cpuCount; j++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }



  var port = parseInt(3000);
  var app = express();

  var server = http.createServer(app);
  app.use(addRequestId);
  app.use(requestIp.mw())
  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false}));
  server.listen(port, () => { })
  console.log("SERVER UP AND RUNNING");

  app.use('/v1/jp', require('./routes/report_center'));



}


cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
  console.log(`Worker ${worker.id} died'`);
  console.log(`Staring a new one...`);
  cluster.fork();
});
```

***report_center.js***

```
const moment = require('moment');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const reports = express.Router();

const mysql = require('mysql');
const async = require("async");
const constants = require('./v1/constant.js');
var _ = require('lodash');


var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 1000,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_DBNAME,
    charset: process.env.DB_CHARSET,
    timezone: 'UTC' + '05:30'
});

/*########################
Middleware  Starts
#########################*/

reports.use(bodyParser.json());
reports.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

reports.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url)
    pool.getConnection(function (err, con) {
        if (err) {

            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                "error_status": true,
                "error": constants.err_desc.error_409,
                "message": constants.customMessage.DB_CON_FAILED
            }))
        } else {

            var queryTofindClient = mysql.format(`select * from client where api_key = ? LIMIT 1;`, [req.headers['api_key']]);

            console.log(queryTofindClient)
            con.query(queryTofindClient, (err, queryTofindClient_res) => {
                if (err) {

                    res.send(JSON.stringify({
                        "error_status": true,
                        "error": constants.err_desc.error_500,
                        "message": constants.customMessage.QUERY_FAILED
                    }))
                } else {

                    if (queryTofindClient_res.length == 0) {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({
                            "error_status": true,
                            "error": constants.err_desc.error_401,
                            "message": constants.customMessage.UNAUTHORISED
                        }))
                    } else {

                        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS,');
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept,x-access-token');
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        next();

                    }
                }
            })
        }
        con.release();
    })

})

/*########################
Middleware  ENDS
#########################*/



reports.get("/get_api", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Ok');
});

reports.post("/post_api", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Ok');
});


module.exports = reports;
```

Error below in screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you add the error message in the question code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara please check the edit

Comment: What happens if you take out your `reports.use(....` middleware?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for two days found the culprit known as a postman which was delivering my letters with a different sender name by which I mean it was just routing all the methods to GET type.

***The below setting in the screenshot was turned off by default.***

[image]

***I just hope it helps someone who does not deserve to get frustrated and do save his time instead unlike like me***